# Extract the table names from the query string using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split, substring

I am trying to extract the substring from the query variable
For example

```
Var query =“SELECT     
  E.NationalIDNumber,
  E.JobTitle,
  P.FirstName,
  P.LastName
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN Person P 
on E.BusinessEntityID = P.BusinessEntityID”;
```

**What is expected?**
I want to extract the table names from the above query. So the result should be for example - **Employee, Person**.
Each time the query will have different structure and tables. Can anyone help me find the easy way to extract this info?

I have broken down the logic as below, but not able to figure how to extract

1. Extract string after  ‘FROM’  keyword and  single space
2. Extract string after  ‘JOIN’ keyword and single space

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to create a regex, for instance we can find the `FROM`, then the word next to it would be the table name. Note that we have to take more cases than you wrote, for instance I added the following cases: `INSERT INTO tablename`, `SELECT ... FROM tablename`, `UPDATE tablename`, `JOIN tablename`.

```js
let strs = ["FROM", "INTO", "UPDATE", "JOIN"];
let query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM users)";
for(let str of strs)
{
    let reg = new RegExp(str + " (\\w+)", "gmi");
    const array = [...query.matchAll(reg)];
    console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: I am using server side java script and when I try to execute the above i get an error

Comment: Provide more details please to why you got an error, what is the error?